# How do you stop jCarouselLite autoplay?

Tags: jquery, autoplay, jcarousellite

I would like to stop the autoplay on jCarouselLite once it gets to the end of the scrollable list. What happens now is that I get to the end of the list, click the back button, then it continues to autoplay.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command .

$('div.carousel').trigger('pauseCarousel');

Also be sure that you are using the latest jcarousellite version

https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-carousel-lite

Comment: I would like to trigger the pause once the carousel has hit the last scrollable area. I guess I am more interested in how to trigger the pauseCarousel at the end of the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

$(".mycarousel").trigger('stopCarousel');

If you're using the newest jcarousel https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-carousel-lite/

This event isn't in their documentation for some reason although pauseCarousel is.  Pause only temporarily pauses, it restarts when you mouse out of the carousel.